# C# Concurrent Dictionary is not adding or updating values in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, concurrentdictionary

I am attempting to cache some key value pairs into a concurrent dictionary in order to avoid going to cosmos every single time I need the value.  Here is my code.

```
public class ActivityLogHubIngress
    {
        private readonly ICustomerDbService _customerDbService;
        
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _customerIdLookup => new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        public ActivityLogHubIngress(ICustomerDbService customerDbService)
        {
            _customerDbService = customerDbService;
        }

        [FunctionName("ActivityLogHubIngress")]
        public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("activity-log-events", Connection = "ActivityLogEventHub")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
        {
         //Some code removed for brevity. At some point in this Azure Function the following line gets called to retrieve a customer ID.
         
         string customerId = await GetCustomerId(activityLogHubEvent.SubscriptionId, log); 

         //Some code removed for brevity. 
        }

private async Task<string> GetCustomerId(string subscriptionId, ILogger log = null)
        {
            if (_customerIdLookup.TryGetValue(subscriptionId, out string customerId))
            {
                return customerId;
            }

            var customer = await _customerDbService.GetCustomerBySubscription(subscriptionId);
            if(customer is null)
            {
                _customerIdLookup.AddOrUpdate(subscriptionId, string.Empty, (key, value) => string.Empty);

                if (log != null)
                {
                    log.LogInformation(ApplicationEvents.ActivityLogUnknownSubscriptionFailure,
                    $"Added Non-Customer ({subscriptionId}: null) to _customerIdLookup" +
                    $"\nListing _customerIdLookup dictionary (item count {_customerIdLookup.Count})" +
                    $"\n{string.Join("\n", _customerIdLookup.Keys.Select(k => $"{k}: {_customerIdLookup[k]}").ToList())}");
                }

                return null;
            }

            _customerIdLookup.AddOrUpdate(subscriptionId, customer.Id, (key, value) => customer.Id);

            if(log != null)
            {
                log.LogInformation(ApplicationEvents.ActivityLogUnknownSubscriptionFailure,
                $"Added ({subscriptionId}: {customer.Id}) to _customerIdLookup" +
                $"\nListing _customerIdLookup dictionary (item count {_customerIdLookup.Count})" +
                $"\n{string.Join("\n", _customerIdLookup.Keys.Select(k => $"{k}: {_customerIdLookup[k]}").ToList())}");
            }                

            return customer.Id;
        }
```

The code executes fine, but the intention is that the value returned by

`var customer = await _customerDbService.GetCustomerBySubscription(subscriptionId);`

would get cached in the _customerIdLookup and then accessed via the dictionary on the next event with the same subscription ID instead of going to cosmos.  However, _customerIdLookup remains empty and the code always routes through Cosmos even though I send multiple events with the same subscription ID.

All my logs look something like this.

```
Added (84b*****-****-****-****-***********0f: 12345678) to _customerIdLookup
Listing _customerIdLookup dictionary (item count 0)
```

Where item count is always zero.

What am I doing incorrectly that the dictionary is not being written to?

Comment: Are you hosting on a serverless (consumption) plan, or on a dedicated App Service plan? Can you guarantee that your function is being run on the same server, in the same process, each time?

Comment: it is a consumption plan, but I can see the server instances spin up in app insights and I was hoping that some of the traffic would be able to share the same static member.  also it seems weird even it each request was going through a different server that the log which is written AFTER the addition would show 0 items in the dictionary.

Comment: Yeah I'm just reading through the code now, I didn't realize you're logging the count immediately within the same method call. Also FYI, I don't think an injected `ILogger` will ever be null. If logging is disabled, the logger will still be injected but it will not output to anything

Comment: Here's a minimal example demonstrating the same behaviour: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vnv2yp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your declaration of the dictionary:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _customerIdLookup => new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Notice the lambda symbol `=>`, this means a new instance will be returned every time you access the member.

Comment: Awesome catch! How did I not see that? I just moved it to a static constructor.  That should fix it. Thanks for being a second set of eyes.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/unPYwV <--- that is the fix.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a static constructor, you can just change it from `=>` to `=`